# How best to measure/compare scroll event function performance JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that determines whether an element is visible on scroll, returning true/false.

I am trying to ascertain which of the following versions of the function is the most efficient / least impactful - one is in jQuery, and the other is vanilla JS.

I'm familiar with using performance.now() to measure execution time of a function but since this is repeatedly called on the scroll event I don't think that applies.

How best to go about this?

**jQuery:**

```
function isVisible( scrollDistance, element ) {

    let wrapperOffset = $('#scroll-wrapper').offset().top;

    var elemOffset = element.offset().top;

    var top = elemOffset - wrapperOffset - wh;
    var btm = elemOffset - wrapperOffset + element.outerHeight();

    if ( scrollDistance > top && scrollDistance < btm ) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Vanilla JS:**

```
function isVisible( scrollDistance, element ) {

    let elem = element[0];

    var wrapperOffset = document.getElementById("scroll-wrapper").getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;
    var elemOffset = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;

    var top = elemOffset - wrapperOffset - wh;
    var btm = elemOffset - wrapperOffset + elem.offsetHeight;

    if ( scrollDistance > top && scrollDistance < btm ) {
        return true 
    }

}
```

---

**EDIT:**

One solution that I've come up with for this is to measure the overall execution time of the functions being run repeatedly within a for loop.

**Note: There are likely several factors impacting the accuracy of this.**

I ran the following loop a few times, calling each function respectively and the results were surprisingly consistent.

For reference the Vanilla JS won out, with approximately ~15ms execution time over the 5000 calls. The jQuery version was a comparatively massive ~135ms.

Interestingly, I swapped out a couple of the lines in the jQuery function and discovered the jQuery offset() had by far the biggest impact, knocking off ~100ms when the line was switched with the vanilla JS equivalent.

**The loop:**

```
let start = performance.now(); // start time

for (x = 0; x < 5000; x++) {

    isVisible( 0, element );

    if ( x == 4999 ) {

        let stop = performance.now(); // end time
        
        console.log( stop-start )

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Intersection Observer` which is better than both in performance for most cases and it is much easier to use, it can determine if the element in the viewport ( visible on the screen ) or not, Also, you can have more control.

It is mostly being used for image lazy loading.

HTML:

```
<img class="lazy-loaded-image lazy" src="PATH_TO_PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE" data-src="PATH_TO_ACTUAL_IMAGE" />
<img class="lazy-loaded-image lazy" src="PATH_TO_PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE" data-src="PATH_TO_ACTUAL_IMAGE" />
<img class="lazy-loaded-image lazy" src="PATH_TO_PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE" data-src="PATH_TO_ACTUAL_IMAGE" />
<img class="lazy-loaded-image lazy" src="PATH_TO_PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE" data-src="PATH_TO_ACTUAL_IMAGE" />
```

JS:

```
var lazyImages = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".lazy-loaded-image.lazy"));

let lazyImageObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
    entries.forEach(function(entry) {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            let lazyImage = entry.target;
            lazyImage.src = lazyImage.dataset.src;
            lazyImage.classList.remove("lazy");
            lazyImageObserver.unobserve(lazyImage);
        }
    });
});
/** Now observe all the non-loaded images using the observer we have setup above **/
lazyImages.forEach(function(lazyImage) {
    lazyImageObserver.observe(lazyImage);
});
```

For more resources How to use them.

https://medium.com/fasal-engineering/image-lazy-loading-using-browsers-intersection-observer-api-a-step-by-step-guide-with-examples-b1a867614e8

https://medium.com/swlh/intersection-observer-in-javascript-efcf13c154ce

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

For compatibility with browsers.

https://caniuse.com/?search=Intersection%20Observer

Comment: Awesome thanks - I hadn't come across this API - looks useful! A couple references on this here in case anyone else wants to explore this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API, https://medium.com/swlh/intersection-observer-in-javascript-efcf13c154ce

Comment: You are welcome, I updated the answer with the resources.

Comment: And may be a link to https://caniuse.com/?search=Intersection%20Observer